# Large infinity category

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

My understanding is that $(\infty,1)$-categories generalise both categories and spaces (topological spaces, Kan complexes or $\infty$-groupoids). One of the most used models for $(\infty,1)$-categories is [quasi-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quasi-category) (aka weak Kan complexes). The fully faithful nerve functor $\mathbf{N}:\mathbf{Cat}\to \mathbf{sSet}$ sends small categories to quasi-categories. So, obviously quasi-categories generalise small catgeoires, but what about large categoires like $\mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{Top}$? The texts I am reading on $(\infty,1)$-categories seem to intentionally ignore some set-theoretic issues as "In these notes we ignore essentially all set-theoretic issues (with the exception of the discussion of locally presentable categories where some care is needed)." in [A short course on $\infty$-categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.2925).

> Is there a developed model for $(\infty,1)$-categories that gerenalise large categories, in addition to small ones? What is a reference that provide a treatment for such models?

Comment: I am looking forward to seeing the answers to this question.

Comment: I would presume the "standard" approach would be to assume suitable Grothendieck universes or even Tarski's axiom, in which case any of the categories we'd be concerned about would be "small" with respect to some universe.

Comment: @DerekElkins: For every Grothendieck universe $\mathfrak{U}$, there is a category  $\mathbf{Set}_{\mathfrak{U}}$ of small sets with respect to $\mathfrak{U}$. So if categories large with respect to $\mathfrak{U}$ are generalised by quasi-categories with respect to a bigger universe $\mathfrak{U}'$, the question remain for the category  $\mathbf{Set}_{\mathfrak{U}'}$. A better formulation of the question: can one fix a foundation and defines categories and a model for $(\infty,1)$-categories in that foundation so that there exist large $(\infty,1)$-categories that generalise large categories?

Comment: Tarksi's axiom states that every set is contained in some Grothendieck universe. So there is a $\mathfrak U''$ such that $\mathbf{Set}_{\mathfrak U'}$ is small with respect to it, and so forth. You can still formulate a notion of "large category" in such a context, but you'd have to be pretty far out there to need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when doing category theory, we work in the settings of Grothendieck universes (or some equivalent set theory).

Then $\mathbf{Set}$ is an abuse for the category of $\mathbb U$-sets for some universe $\mathbb U$ which is clear from the context, it should be denoted $\mathbb U{\text-}\mathbf{Set}$. The axiom of universes then assures that $\mathbb U\text-\mathbf{Set}$ is a $\mathbb V$-small category for a big enough universe $\mathbb V$. Now $\mathbb U\text-\mathbf{Set}$ can be seen, through its nerve, as an object in ${\mathbb V\text-\mathbf{Set}}^{\Delta^{\rm op}}$. The same goes for $\mathbf{Top}$, which is actually a shortcut for the category $\mathbb U\text-\mathbf{Top}$ of topological spaces with $\mathbb U$-small underlying sets.

If you really want to work in a foundationnal setting that only allows two levels (small and large) as NBG, you can still defined what a simplicial class is, and you can still require this simplicial class to fill some horns, leading eventually to a non small quasi-category. You will just not be able to see them as simplicial objects of some category, that's all. You can also adopt another model of $(\infty,1)$-categories as [Kan complexes enriched categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicially+enriched+category#as_models_for_categories).

Comment: Thank you, Kan complexes enriched categories would be a suitable model. However, for the different universes approach, the question remain for the category $\mathbb V\text-\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @user24453 Not really, by the same axiom of universes you get a universe $\mathbb W$ such that $\mathbb V\text-\mathbf{Set}$ is $\mathbb W$-small, et so on.